# Mapping One Table Row To Another Table Multiple Rows

Tags: sql-server, database, mapping

I have a question which i don't know if it's possible.

lets say i have 3 tables:

> Offices: Id, Name
>
> Contacts : id , first_name, last_name, email, office_id
>
> Sites : id, ip_addr, dns_addr, name, office_id

let say i have 2 sites under the same office_id, but they have a different contacts.
how can i map between one row of Sites to multiple rows in Contacts??

i'm not too fimiliar with db architcure, so maybe i orgenized my db tables wrong?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can a contact of one site also be a contact at another site?  Or does each contact have one and only one site?

Comment: does it matter? can you give me the option of yes \ no?

Comment: Yes it matters.  If a contact is only ever related to one site then adding a single foreign key that links site to contact and your done.  If a contact can be related to more than one site then tracking the relationships requires a separate table (as mentioned in the answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current structure of your DB doesn't associate a `Site` with a `Contact` at all - both are related to the `office`.

The easiest way to do what you are after would be to create a lookup table that associates a `Contact.id` with a `Site.id`.

The problem you will have with this is there will be no inherent integrity checks - you can associate a contact with a site that's not affiliated with the same office.  The major benefit here is you can have multiple contacts per site, or multiple sites per contact.